# Removing Special Characters from JSON in NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

I have JSON input for Nifi flow with some special characters. Could someone help me with how to remove special characters following payload? we would need only value with array and double-quotes.

input json:

```json
{
  "TOT_NET_AMT": "["55.00"]",
  "H_OBJECT": "File",
  "H_GROSS_AMNT": "["55.00"]",
  "TOT_TAX_AMT": "[9.55]"
}
```

Expected Result :

```json
{
  "TOT_NET_AMT": "55.00",
  "H_OBJECT": "File",
  "H_GROSS_AMNT": "55.00",
  "TOT_TAX_AMT": "9.55"
}
```

Comment: the format of the input JSON is wrong in the current state

Comment: removed jsonpath label as it is a query syntax.  it cannot modify the input document.

Comment: Barbaros is correct that the input is not valid JSON.  It looks like there are extra quotes that probably need to be escaped.

Comment: You could just open as text and do some two text replacements. Replacing "[" for " and "]" for "